# How can I upadate with jooq using map?

Tags: java, jooq

I want to update a table of ORACLE using other table data. I tried putting the data into map and setting them with jooq.The format of the data is not problem but it doesn't work. Summary Code is here.

```
Map <String, Object> testMap = dbDataMap

DSL.update(table)
   .set(testMap)
   .where(condition)
   .execute();
```

Or I  tried

```
Map <String, Object> testMap = dbDataMap

DSL.update(table)
   .set(DSL.row(testMap.keySet(),(RowN)testMap.values())
   .where(condition)
   .execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

The second approach should work like this:

```
DSL.update(table)
   .set(DSL.row(testMap.keySet()), DSL.row(testMap.values())
   .where(condition)
   .execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DSL.row()` for both keys and values to set.

```
DSL.update(table)
   .set(DSL.row(testMap.keySet()), DSL.row(testMap.values())
   .where(condition)
   .execute();
```

You will found more details in official [doc](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/update-statement/#N6FB37)